# \pdfstringdefDisableCommands with starred and non starred commands

Tags: macros, hyperref, bookmarks, section-titles, starred-version

The following MCE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \foo } { s m } {
  \IfBooleanTF {#1}{
    Foo~ #2
  }{
    #2
  }
}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{
  \def\foo*#1{Foo~ #1}
  % \def\foo#1{#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\section{\foo*{bar}}
% \section{\foo{bar}}
\end{document}
```

compiles like a charm, except if the `\section{\foo{bar}}` is uncommented, the error message being in such a case:

```
! Use of \foo doesn't match its definition.
<argument> ...rline {\csname thesection\endcsname }\fi \foo {
                                                  bar}
```

Is there a way to use `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` with both starred and non starred commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to redefine the command using the same signature as the original command.  Since `s m` is a valid signature for an expandable command, you can just redefine using `\RenewExpandableDocumentCommand`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \foo } { s m } {
  \IfBooleanTF {#1}{
    Foo~ #2
  }{
    #2
  }
}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{
  \RenewExpandableDocumentCommand \foo { s m }
    { Foo~ #2 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\section{\foo*{bar}}
\section{\foo{bar}}
\end{document}
```

Note that in your example, the command `\foo` contains only expandable macros, so it can work in an expansion-only context, so if you define it using `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` directly, you don't need to redefine for `hyperref`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand { \foo } { s m } {
  \IfBooleanTF {#1}{
    Foo~ #2
  }{
    #2
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\section{\foo*{bar}}
\section{\foo{bar}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: AFAICS, your second method which makes use of `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` leads to ”Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):“ warning if the `\foo` command involves a `\cs_new_protected:Npn` function.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Yes, because in that case, `\foo` contains a non-expandable token, thus, it cannot be expandable.  I meant that in the _specific_ case of the example you posted, the whole function can be made expandable. I clarified the text in the answer