# How to \NewDocumentCommand/RenewDocumentCommand using \texordpdfstring?

Tags: spacing, texorpdfstring

I use `\,`, `\thinspace` and my own hairspace-command `\hrsp` all the time, but I don't want to care whether it's used in a pdf-string (often in sectioning- and cite-commands), which is to get rid of `Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): (hyperref)                removing \hrsp on input line 334.`

I want to (re-)define the command so that they do different things whether used in `TeX` or `PDF string`, perhaps by means of `\texorpdfstring{}{}`.

We don't need a MWE, all we need is:

```
% -*- mode: latex; TeX-engine: luatex; coding: utf-8; -*-
\usepackage[twothirds]{thinsp}
\NewDocumentCommand{\hrsp}{}{\ifmmode\mskip1mu\else\kern.08333em\fi}
```

As PDF string `\hrsp` should do nothing, i.e. insert no space at all, whereas `\,` should insert an ordinary interword-space when `\thinspace` is not able to be used.

---

OK, I added to my preamble

```
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \def\,{ }%
  \def\hrsp{}%
}
```

which works fine.

Comment: You're probably looking for `NewExpandableDocumentCommand`, but with its limitations.

Comment: Not really. I can understand the question without one, but a MWE here helps us quickly confirm that our answer **works** before we post it.

Comment: You can redefine macros in pdf strings, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/330980/82917.

Comment: I agree with campa, it is super useful to be able to change macros before they are used in pdf strings. Especially providing simpler expandable versions.

Comment: see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/643568/2388